# Reassign Quartz jobs on server failure

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have configure Quartz JDBCJobStore to run some schedulers on a clustered app and while testing what would happen if one of the servers goes down in the middle of a job processing I found that Quartz does not have a mechanism for the other instances of the app to figure out if one job could not be finished by one of the servers and should be reassign to another one, the problem is that when a server fails it does not have the opportunity to released the lock that it has over the job in the database, so the Job basically stays locked until someone removes the lock by hand.

Is there a built-in feature in Quartz that allow to handle this type of situation (to detect if a job should be release from its lock)?

Comment: org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html) is used by quartz to detect nodes that are down. If a node goes down while processing task, other nodes will take over after clusterCheckinInterval millis have passed. Are you not seeing that behavior?

Comment: @Srinivas That check is stored in a table called `QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE`, the problem with that table is that it does not have a column to identify the node that is performing the check in so when a node goes down the other nodes keep updating the entry an quartz never notice that there is a job that was locked by a down node

Comment: Ok, I checked the documentation and I was missing this property `org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO`, without that quartz is unable to identify the different active nodes, so I added that and the problem seems to be solved, @Srinivas thanks a lot, your comment lead me to the solution.